# SQL autoincrement id field add letter

Tags: sql

I have this issue please.
I have this sql query here:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO formas (data,dyqani_pergjegjes,pranoi) VALUES ('$postData','$postDyqani_pergjegjes','$postPranoi')";
```

I have an autoincrement id field here, what i need is to add a letter "A" in front of the id which auto increases...
How can i do that?
Thanks

Comment: and what DBMS are you using?

Comment: Find the maximum value of the id. Using substring concept take the integer value and add one to the value. Now concatenate "A" and the integer value. Now u can persist the incremented value.

Comment: rdbms driver should return generated value. You can just append A to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want another readonly field (varchar, e.g. **A_id**) based upon the **id** field -

```
UPDATE table SET A_id='A'+cast(id as varchar)
-- sets all in the table, or add a WHERE clause to do the one you've just added
```